# Prevent save state hover in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have an application, with fabricjs. It works with the zoom of the mousewheel, when I do mousewheel up, my canvas save the state, like as if  I do mousewheel down.

I have a state in the canvas when I put the mouse over on an object.
When you are hovering an object and do zoom-in and zoom-out, the state of the canvas is saved with the hover state. I don't want this to happen. How I can prevent this?

```
//click on the rect to see that the color red is saved in the json
//shown in the console log, but i want the original State, the red fill
canvas.on("mouse:over", function(event){
 if("target" in event){
    color = event.target.fill;
    event.target.fill="red";
    canvas.renderAll();
 }
});
canvas.on("mouse:out", function(event){
 if("target" in event){
    event.target.fill=color;
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
});

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: 'blue',
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  angle: 45
});
canvas.add(rect);
```

You can check the fiddle at: 
https://jsfiddle.net/samael205/xtcmokuy/9/

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to just ignore the hover state. You can save the color in some other field and pass that field in to the `toObject()` call and the reset it after the export.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  perPixelTargetFind: true
});

canvas.on("mouse:down", function(event) {
  var state = canvas.toObject(['trueColor']);
  state.objects.forEach(o => {
    if (o.trueColor) {
      o.fill = o.trueColor;
    }
  })
  console.log(state);
});
//click on the rect to see that the color red is saved in the json
//shown in the console log, but i want the original State, the red fill
canvas.on("mouse:over", function(event) {
  if (event.target) {
    event.target.trueColor = event.target.fill;
    event.target.fill = "red";
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
});
canvas.on("mouse:out", function(event) {
  if (event.target) {
    event.target.fill = event.target.trueColor;
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
});

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: 'blue',
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  angle: 45
});
canvas.add(rect);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.6/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, Works fine.

Comment: ´code´ var state = canvas.toObject(propiedadesAdicionales);
   state.objects.forEach( function(o, index) {
    if("originalColor" in o){
     switch(o.type){
      case "line":
       o.stroke = o.originalColor;
      break;
      case "image":
      break;
      default:
       o.fill = o.originalColor;
     }
    }
    if(o.type == "image"){
     if(matrix.get_filter_Tint(o)){
      if(matrix.get_filter_Tint_color(o) == "red"){
       matrix.applyFilterTint("red", 0.5, o);
      }
     }
    }
   });
  return JSON.stringify(state);

Comment: ups. sorry, i dont kow how to insert code... but, that works fine